# Is there a way to set settings/environment variables per terminal/bash - Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, script

I'm relatively new to using Linux and just recently had a very interesting request to assists testing at the company I work for. Testers tests application through terminal commands and separate which product line they are testing by using separate terminals. Sometimes PATHing can cause issues here as several executable are not uniquely named and the applications fork to relative paths. **In this regard I would like to create a script that users/testers can run that sets environment variables that are local to each terminal session and can define the specific executables that should run when called.** Is there a universal way in Linux to do this? THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with an ordinary script — users must use the `source` command to process the command file(s) you write.  If you can edit the users’ `.bashrc` files (or tell the users what to put there), consider using `alias` commands.

Comment: After reviewing my options is it possible to use a script file to run an export PATH=these/particular/files command?

Comment: Yes — but your users will need to `source` your script.  In *nix and Unix-like systems, process characteristics/ properties get passed from parent to child, but never the other way around.  For example, if you set your `PATH` to include `/foo`, and then you run a script that tries to run `bar`, it will find `/foo/bar` — but if you change `PATH` in an ordinary script (one that’s run just by typing its name), it doesn’t affect your interactive shell.